# orientjs: query result Bag.all() returns empty array

Tags: node.js, orientdb, orientjs

I`m using OrientJS with nodeJS to perform a query using .query() method.
I get results, but I can`t extract the in_ and out_ fields, as they`re of a 'Bag' type.

When I try .all() method to get the results I get an array[0]. 
When I perform the same query in Studio I see that the in_ and out_ fields are not empty.

[image: Stdio result for query][image]

Comment: can you provide an example script ?

Comment: I dont quite understand what you need, but this is the code line running the query:`(this.db.query('select from v where entity_id in ["person_p186"]')`

Comment: Hi, can you post all the code and also an example of the structure? Thx

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response....

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response....
Im not quite sure what you mean by data structure, can you elaborate? 
Regarding the code, It is very complicated and big, doing all kinds of different things... The only reference to OrientDb is using `this.db` which is of type `OrientDb.Db` of the orientjs library....

Comment: The query and receiving the response:
`this.db.query('select from v where entity_id in "person_p186"]').then(function (results) {`

Comment: if you do JSON.stringify(result[0]) ?

Comment: Here a working example

https://gist.github.com/maggiolo00/cda5589a1b63403aaf107770a26e9d9f

Comment: So... the tree ridbag is not supported in orientjs currently which is why

Answer (score 0):

Our edges are tree based, and tree based ridbags are not currently supported by OrientJs as can be seen [here](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientjs/issues/29). This is why we did not get any results.
Embedded RIDbags are supported.